# I get Error when i run enable-migrations in package manager console

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am making a ASP.NET MVC project ...when i type enable-migrations i get the following eroors:

```
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'eManager.Web'.
To enable migrations for eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb.
To enable migrations for eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext.
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error message exactly states what the problem is and what needs to be done - including the command that needs to be issued. Apparently there is more than one context in your project (Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb and Web.Models.UsersContext) and migrations does not know for which of these migrations should be enabled. You need to point to the context type. As per the error message use:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb.
```

to enable migrations for eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDb or

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext.
```

to enable migrations for eManager.Web.Models.UsersContext

Comment: thank you very much for the help ... i am a new bie to mvc ... so i was stuck with this migrations .. in the tutorial im refering they just type only enable-migraitons and things work ...

Comment: Yeah, tutorials typically focus on the simplest case. If you had had just one context simple Enable-Migrations would have just work.

Comment: can you plz suggest me ... some book for learning asp.net mvc in detail ...  i am not having a good knowledge about abstraction and interface etc, ... i have been working in n-tier architecture..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any book but I think you can find plenty off good tutorials on the web. I would start from here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4. In addition, if you really want to know what's going there, MVC is open source and you can just look at the code. Here is the codeplex site http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: This is an error message from the Pluralsight Tutorial. It's caused because you create a MVC application that has a users context created automatically, and in the tutorial you create the DepartmentDB. The correct choice in this case is choosing DepartmentDb.

Comment: I have the same problem, But I dont want multiple contexts, how do i remove them?

Comment: @JeremyMorgan ... Don't you just love coming across errors in tutorials :(

Answer (score 1):

For those that may want to remain with a single context in the project. In this case, it will be the DepartmentDb context.

Move the below code into your DepartmentDb context:

```html
public DepartmentDb() 
: base("DefaultConnection")
{

}

public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

Next: Get to your AccountModels.cs and delete/comment out the UsersContext class.
You will get build errors - so replace the UsersContext references with DepartmentDb.

Build again and it should succeed.

Now go to the Package Manager Console and run PM> enable-migrations

You should get "Code First Migrations enabled for project eManager.Web."